# script to compare two files and remove match line in file A

Tags: text-processing, text-editor, text

I have two files.
file A:

```
Modern Tales: Age Of Invention Playstation 4, 1935, 3478-3480
Modern Tales: Age Of Invention Xbox One, 3074
Moero Chronicle Switch, 6667, 12400, 28910, 29900, 29901, 29920
MOHAA Counter Intelligence, 
MOHAA MatchWatch, 950, 5500-5699, 13000-14000
MOHAA Missionary, 
Mokoko X Switch, 6667, 12400, 28910, 29900, 29901, 29920
Mokoko X Xbox One, 3074
```

and file B:

```
MIX Game Server
MOHAA Counter Intelligence
MOHAA MatchWatch
MOHAA Missionary
MOHAA Reverend
MoneyWorks Datacentre
Monsoon Vulkano
Moonlight Game Streaming
MY-IPCAM Anywhere
```

How can I remove entire lines form file A where its first column are identical in file B?
Final file should be:

```
Modern Tales: Age Of Invention Playstation 4, 1935, 3478-3480
Modern Tales: Age Of Invention Xbox One, 3074
Moero Chronicle Switch, 6667, 12400, 28910, 29900, 29901, 29920
Mokoko X Switch, 6667, 12400, 28910, 29900, 29901, 29920
Mokoko X Xbox One, 3074
```

Comment: I see you asked the opposite of this question here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1459425/968501 … Just remove the `-v` option in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1459415/968501 if that answer worked for you in this question … or remove the `!` in the `awk` solution in this answer  https://askubuntu.com/a/1459419/968501 And the should both solve your new question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep` for this task, so to remove the file from `fileA.txt` that are the sames lines as in the file `fileB.txt` it will be:

```
grep -v -w -F -f fileB.txt fileA.txt > fileA_filtered.txt
```

`fileA_filtered.txt` will contain all the lines from those 2 files that were not the same.

Comment: Do you actually need `-w` when matching a fixed string using `grep`?

Comment: @Raffa it does seem to impose regex-style word boundary assertions even in fixed-string mode - try `echo foo | grep -Fw oo` for example

Comment: @steeldriver It does indeed, but kind of defy the purpose of `-F` and will work the same(*or at least the same end result*) without it ... i.e. `echo foo | grep -w oo`

Comment: @steeldriver After testing(*judging by user CPU time when processing very large files*) it appears that with both `-F` and `-Fw` very close CPU time is used while with only `-w` CPU time is clearly, distinctively and significantly much greater ... Therefore I assume using `-Fw` can be both harmless and justified in some cases IMHO :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to match on the first comma-separated *field* rather than anywhere in the line you can do so with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} !($1 in a)' file_B file_A
Modern Tales: Age Of Invention Playstation 4, 1935, 3478-3480
Modern Tales: Age Of Invention Xbox One, 3074
Moero Chronicle Switch, 6667, 12400, 28910, 29900, 29901, 29920
Mokoko X Switch, 6667, 12400, 28910, 29900, 29901, 29920
Mokoko X Xbox One, 3074
```

Alternatively, since your files appear to be pre-sorted on the first field, you could use the `join` command:

```
$ join -t, -j 1 -v 1 file_A file_B
Modern Tales: Age Of Invention Playstation 4, 1935, 3478-3480
Modern Tales: Age Of Invention Xbox One, 3074
Moero Chronicle Switch, 6667, 12400, 28910, 29900, 29901, 29920
Mokoko X Switch, 6667, 12400, 28910, 29900, 29901, 29920
Mokoko X Xbox One, 3074
```