# Compare two files and remove every line that doesn't match with file B

Tags: text-processing, text

I have two files. file A:

```
Modern Tales: Age Of Invention Playstation 4, 1935, 3478-3480
Modern Tales: Age Of Invention Xbox One, 3074
Moero Chronicle Switch, 6667, 12400, 28910, 29900, 29901, 29920
MOHAA Counter Intelligence, 
MOHAA MatchWatch, 950, 5500-5699, 13000-14000
MOHAA Missionary, 
Mokoko X Switch, 6667, 12400, 28910, 29900, 29901, 29920
Mokoko X Xbox One, 3074
```

and file B:

```
MIX Game Server
MOHAA Counter Intelligence
MOHAA MatchWatch
MOHAA Missionary
MOHAA Reverend
MoneyWorks Datacentre
Monsoon Vulkano
Moonlight Game Streaming
MY-IPCAM Anywhere
```

How can I remove every line from file A that doesn't match in file b.
Final file should be:

```
MOHAA Counter Intelligence, 
MOHAA MatchWatch, 950, 5500-5699, 13000-14000
MOHAA Missionary,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$ grep -f file_b file_a
MOHAA Counter Intelligence, 
MOHAA MatchWatch, 950, 5500-5699, 13000-14000
MOHAA Missionary,
```